# Why is my threads_connected ALWAYS = 1?

Tags: mysql

I run a website with fairly high traffic. I've been having a lot of issues lately with "too many connections" or "could not connect" to MySQL and I think it's because of bots but I'm not 100% positive. I connect to the database using one username. So anyone who visits the site connects with the same script (and MySQL user).

If I have 1,000 people on the site at one time and I `show processlist`, the `threads_connected` is always `1`. Is that normal? Could this be the cause of the too many connections issue?

The strange thing is, I can have 20,000 people on the site and it runs fine. But MySQL has been crashing a lot lately with an average of 200 people on the site - which my Amazon instance can EASILY handle. And there are always bots in the `access_log` when it goes down. I have tried so many things to stop MySQL from crashing and nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different issues -- threads *connected* and threads *running*.

In a typical, well oiled, production server, you will see this in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`:

- Lots of "Sleep" connections,
- Fewer than `max_connections` lines in the processlist,
- One, or a small number, of non-Sleep connections.
- Most queries are so fast that they go back to Sleep before you notice it.  I often see "thousands of Queries per second", yet "nothing running".  This is good.

"Sleep" means that the connection is not running a query at the moment.  Instead it might be doing application processing, or it might be part of a "connection pool".

The reason you always see "1" is that you have to run a query (`SHOW PROCESSLIST` or something else) to get the number.  So the "1" is itself.

You said `Threads_connected` is always 1.  Did you mean `Threads_running`?  Note also the capitalization.

What is the value of `thread_cache_size`?  8 is typical, but the exact value does not matter a lot.

What about `Max_used_connections` and `max_connections`?

Is there any sort of "connection pooling"?  Are there multiple clients?

Consider providing me with the info mentioned in tuning [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis) .

Comment: I notice when the website goes down, (mysql stops responding or connection times out), that there is a lot of bot traffic. Applebot, twitterbot, bingbot, googlebot, pinterestbot are common browsers. Now it shows that they request the robots.txt file and get the sitemap - I thought that should alleviate them from browsing the entire site randomly.

What can I do to keep these bots from overloading the connections to mysql? I have spent months trying to solve this. Slowing crawl rate, a dynamic sitemap, editing the settings on max connections etc,. I do not use connection pooling.

Comment: Limit the number of connections to the _client_.  What are you using for your web server?  Apache?  Nginx?  Tomcat?  etc.  Find the setting it has; decrease it.  But wait!  Why would a bot be touching the database??

Comment: Apache Amazon. Doesn't the bot have to connect to the database to pull the content? Every page is loaded from the database using a single connection.

Answer (score 0):

To STOP all the bots, check out this link.  http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/restricting-bots/how-to-stop-search-engines-from-crawling-your-website

Recap, robots.txt needs simply two lines.
User-agent: *

Disallow: /

in the TXT file at the root of your site.